# Unable to create storage account from portal : name already taken

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

I am unable to create a storage account from Portal.

As soon as I type the name it shows error
The storage account name '' is already taken.

I coudlnt find the account in Azure so it doesnt exist definitely. I want to use the same name. I can create storage account with diff name but dont want to.

Anyone knows why this error ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Storage account name you choose must be unique across Azure.

You can check the name availability using the REST API. Refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/checknameavailability).

**Edit:**

As suggested by **Juunas**, Storage account must be unique across all subscriptions globally, not just yours. The reason for that is that the name becomes part of the URL, e.g. `https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net`. Since the URL needs to resolve to a single account, there is no way to have two accounts with the same name.

Comment: It might be good to specify that it must be unique across _all_ subscriptions globally, not just yours. The reason for that is that the name becomes part of the URL, e.g. `https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net`. Since the URL needs to resolve to a single account, there is no way to have two accounts with the same name.

Comment: Yes which is why I find it strange you can't just use

Get-AzStorageAccount -StorageAccountName "test"

You have to specify the resource group name

Get-AzStorageAccount -StorageAccountName "test" -ResourceGroupName "webservers"

Answer (score 1):

The storage account name is actually the subdomain name, so it must be "Globally" unique. Later you can access it through a URL like `yourdomain.file.core.windows.net`